# SQL Conditional Sum and Max Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following information in a table called TankInfo:

`Tank   Compartment Product   _Date     _Time   Volume
  x           x1    GAS     2017-08-02  10:42   10000
  x           x2    GAS     2017-08-02  10:44   20000
  x           x1    GAS     2017-08-02  13:42   9000
  x           x2    GAS     2017-08-02  13:39   20000
  x           x1    GAS     2017-08-02  23:42   9000
  x           x2    GAS     2017-08-02  23:54   21000
  y           y1    GAS     2017-08-02  10:42   10000 
  y           y2    DIESEL  2017-08-02  10:43   5000
  y           y1    GAS     2017-08-02  14:42   10000
  y           y2    DIESEL  2017-08-02  14:52   5000
  y           y1    GAS     2017-08-02  23:12   10000
  y           y2    DIESEL  2017-08-02  23:51   5000`

I need to be able to add the Compartment Volume together if they are the same tank and carry the same product, summing only the max time records together. So the previous table would be summarized to look like the following:

`Tank   Product   _Date     _Time   Volume
  x      GAS    2017-08-02  23:54   30000
  y      GAS    2017-08-02  23:12   10000
  y      DIESEL 2017-08-02  23:51   5000`

I was thinking I could do the following:

```
Select 
    z.Tank
    ,z.Product
    ,z._Date
    --,z._Time
    ,sum(Volume) Volume
from (
Select 
    ti.Tank
    ,ti.Compartment
    ,ti.Product 
    ,ti._Date
    ,max(ti._Time) _Time
from TankInfo ti
Group by
    ti.Tank
    ,ti.Compartment
    ,ti.Product 
    ,ti._Date
) z 
left join(
Select 
    Tank
    ,Compartment
    ,Product 
    ,_Date
    ,_Time
    ,Volume
from TankInfo
) x
    on x.Tank = z.Tank
    and x.Compartment = z.Compartment
    and x.Product = z.Product
    and x._Time = z._Time
Group by
    z.Tank
    ,z.Product
    ,z._Date
```

When running this, I get the following table, and I am stuck with how I can get the max time in as well. Any ideas?

```
Tank    Product        _Date    _Time   Volume
x         GAS       2017-08-02  23:42   9000
x         GAS       2017-08-02  13:39   21000
y         GAS       2017-08-02  23:12   10000
y         DIESEL    2017-08-02  23:51   5000
```

Comment: How volume 30000 for first row?

Comment: It is 30,000 for the first row because it looks at the max times for x1 and x2, and adds the two volumes together. 21000 + 9000 and summaries this for the tank x as 30000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CTE to combine your date and time into one column of type datetame so you can properly aggregate, find the max timestamp and join on the timestamp to get the correct volume:

```
WITH TI (Tank, Compartment, Product, _Date, _Time, TimeStamp, Volume)
AS (SELECT Tank, Compartment, Product, _Date, _Time,
    (CAST(_Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(_Time AS DATETIME)) AS TimeStamp, Volume
    FROM TankInfo)
SELECT 
    TI.Tank, 
    TI.Product, 
    CAST(MAX(TimeStamp) AS date) AS _Date, 
    CAST(MAX(TimeStamp) AS time) AS _Time, 
    SUM(TI.Volume) AS Volume
FROM TI
JOIN (SELECT Tank, Product, MAX(TimeStamp) AS MaxTimeStamp
      FROM TI GROUP BY Tank, Compartment, Product) AS TIAggregated 
      ON TI.TimeStamp =  TIAggregated.MaxTimeStamp
GROUP BY TI.Tank, TI.Product
ORDER BY SUM(TI.Volume) DESC
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
select tp.Tank, tp.Product, max(convert(datetime, latest._Date) + latest._Time), sum(latest.Volume)
from (select distinct Tank, Product from TankInfo) tp
cross apply (
    select top 1 * from TankInfo
    where Tank=tp.Tank and Product=tp.Product
    order by _Date desc, _Time desc) latest
group by tp.Tank, tp.Product
```

Comment: This is a really good solution (although you should use table aliases in the subquery).

Answer (score 1):

So the answer posted by Laghing Vergil will only work if all of your data is the same day.

Sadly, in my attempt I couldn't think of anything cleaner because, as you mentioned, the date/time information is stored (and I assume is intended to be reported in) separate columns.

But this is what I was able to come up with:

```
WITH last_fill AS
(--Get the last time each tank/product pair was filled.
SELECT
    tank,
    product,
    _date,
    _time,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tank, product ORDER BY _date DESC, _time DESC) AS highlander
FROM tankinfo
), last_fill_volume AS
(--Get the last time each compartment was filled.
SELECT
    tank,
    compartment,
    product,
    _date,
    _time,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tank, compartment, product ORDER BY _date DESC, _time DESC) AS highlander
FROM tankinfo
)
SELECT
    ti.tank,
    ti.product,
    lf._date,
    lf._time,
    SUM(ti.volume) AS total_volume
FROM
    tankinfo ti
    INNER JOIN last_fill lf
        ON
        (
            ti.tank = lf.tank AND
            ti.product = lf.product AND
            lf.highlander = 1
        )
    INNER JOIN last_fill_volume lfv
        ON
        (
            ti.tank = lfv.tank AND
            ti.compartment = lfv.compartment AND
            ti.product = lfv.product AND
            ti._date = lfv._date AND
            ti._time = lfv._time AND
            lfv.highlander = 1
        )
GROUP BY ti.tank,ti.product,lf._date,lf._time
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT tank, product, MAX(CAST(_date as datetime) + _time), SUM(Volume) as Volume
FROM (SELECT ti.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tank, product ORDER BY _date DESC, _time DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tankinfo ti
     ) ti
WHERE seqnum = 1
GROUP BY tank, product;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add MAX() around your time value, e.g.

```
Select 
    z.Tank
    ,z.Product
    ,z._Date
    ,Max(z._Time) _Time
    ,sum(Volume) Volume
from (
Select 
    ti.Tank
    ,ti.Compartment
    ,ti.Product 
    ,ti._Date
    ,max(ti._Time) _Time
from TankInfo ti
Group by
    ti.Tank
    ,ti.Compartment
    ,ti.Product 
    ,ti._Date
) z 
left join(
Select 
    Tank
    ,Compartment
    ,Product 
    ,_Date
    ,_Time
    ,Volume
from TankInfo
) x
    on x.Tank = z.Tank
    and x.Compartment = z.Compartment
    and x.Product = z.Product
    and x._Time = z._Time
Group by
    z.Tank
    ,z.Product
    ,z._Date
```